# How to fix http_parser deprecated warning in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently update my angular project from the 8 to 9 version and I face this error

> (node:5716) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

[image]

If anybody has a solution to remove this warning. it's very much appreciated!

Comment: Use an alternative...

Comment: @LoganDevine what alternative, please explain

Comment: Did you solve?  @RobinSingh

Comment: im facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of errors generally occur due to version conflict. in my case it occurred when the nodejs version was accidently upgraded to 20.1.0 while requited version was 14.15.1